# Hyper-V 2012 move fails to another Hyper-V 2012 host while using Windows 8 machine to do the move

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8, hyper-v-server-2012

I have 2 machines with Hyper-V 2012 (free, console version) that I manage from Windows 8. Whenever I want to move any machines from there's always this error. I have enabled Kerberos, I setup delegation on both hosts (all delegations, not just the necessary ones), I have disabled firewall's and I am even logged in as Domain Admin to both machines. I have re logged multiple times but it still fails. I've read that it's best to move machines from the HOST that is the source but since it's Hyper-V 2012 free version (core) there's no GUI there so I can't do it directly. So I'm using Windows 8 Pro.

[image]

As additional information using powershell command (on the SOURCE host) works just fine (had to adjust some settings in the VM as the other host has less RAM but using following command makes the move:

```
PS C:\> move-vm -Name WEB -DestinationHost HOSTHV4 -DestinationStoragePath 'C:\VM-4\WEB'
```

Comment: don't they have to be in a failover cluster together for livemigration?

Comment: No, I have other client and installed Windows 2012 STD there with Hyper-V role and there's no problem. Just that I am doing move's, replication setup from the source servers as there is GUI. Here I don't have GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this myself and it ended up being a small omission on my part in the confirugation.  Did you remember to change the Authentication protocol for Live Migrations from the default of Credential Security Support Provider (CredSSP) to Kerberos?  This needs to be done on both servers.  I am including a screenshot of the setting I'm referring to.

[image: Hyper-V Settings Page]

Comment: Yes I have everything configured just like on your screen. It just doesn't work if i am not doing move from the command line on the machine that has source.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with delegation.  You need to go into active directory and give the machines delegation to each other.  You'll want to for both the cifs service and the Microsoft Virtual System Migration Service.

Should look similar to this

[image: example configuration]

Comment: I have that. It works fine with command line. Just not thru GUI of Windows 8.

Comment: I've had that happen a few times and a reboot on everything fixed it for me.